# how to include range for eg 'if numbers are between 1 to 5' in swift

Tags: swift, range

I need to code in swift for 'if numbers are between 1 to 5'

I tried this but it's not working.

```
    if myPercent == (1 ... 5) {
        let numberGroup = 1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use two conditions to check whether it's in bounds:

```
if myPercent >= 1 && myPercent <= 5 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Great @Aurora0001 - this worked perfectly. I accept this answer, with thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I would test to see if my solution or @dasblinkenlight's one performs better: I suspect the `contains` method will be slow for large ranges but it's probably fine here.

Answer (score 8):

Use `contains`:

```
if (1...5).contains(myPercent) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Yes that works in my code. Great

Comment: This should be the answer.  It is cleaner than the previous.

Comment: OOPer's answer is the proper one. Please use that instead @TheValyreanGroup

Answer (score 8):

`contains` seems to be the basic manner to work with range.

Here are some additions...

Use pattern matching operator:

```
if 1...5 ~= myPercent {
    //...
}
```

Use if-case:

```
if case 1...5 = myPercent {
    //...
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks @OOpPer nice and simple. That's what I was looking for - I knew my try at it was close, this is what I was trying to get to.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an extension combined with a [switch statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID131):

```
extension Int {
    func isBetween(range:Range<Int>) -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case range:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This makes implementation far easier:

```
5.isBetween(1...5) // true
6.isBetween(1...5) // false
```

Note that for this to work in Xcode 8 / Swift 3 you must use the half-open range operator:

```
5.isBetween(1..<6) // true
6.isBetween(1..<6) // false
```

So in your instance:

```
if myPercent.isBetween(1..<6) {
    let numberGroup = 1
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
let numberGroup = myPercent.isBetween(range: 1..<6) ? 1 : 0
```